# Passing array as value of radio button

Tags: php, mysql, forms, radio-button

Is it possible to pass 2 values for a radio button using PHP? I need to write two values to two different columns in MySQL table but the values of the radio button are related.

So, for the radio button, they have a show id and title id. Both need to be written to a column in another table.

How do I pass both ids from the same radio button value? Or what would be an alternative?

Comment: you could do something like `<input type="radio" value="showid|titleid">` and parse the two values out

Comment: Apparently you can determine one value from the radio the user selects, correct?  So why not test the $_POST["myradio"] value in PHP and create another variable to write to data.  Or you could use jquery on the client side to populate a <input type="hidden"..

Comment: please show ur code...